# Python3 list index Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Recently, I have started learning Python. I'd like to make a cosine distribution simulation. 
   "Index Error:list index out of range" is shown on my display. but I think I define a length of list, and I write  0 < key < len(thickness). why the Error is shown on my display??

```
import math

def main():
    height = 20 
    thickness = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
    with open('output/output.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as f:
        f.write('x,thikcness\n')
        for t in range(90):
            deg = t
            rad = math.radians(deg)
            x = height * math.tan(rad)
            key = round(x)

            if 0 < key <= len(thickness):
                thickness[key] += 1


        for t in len(thickness):
            f.write(str(thickness[t]) + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Because you wrote `key <= len(thickness)` instead of `key < len(thickness)`

Comment: To elaborate, the indices of thickness begin at 0 in python, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `if 0 <= key < len(thickness):`. This is because array indices go from `0` to `len(thickness)-1`, not `1` to `len(thickness)`.